# Rails not decoding array of hashes from jQuery correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, decode

In my view I save an array of hashes in a hidden field

```
    <div>
       <%= hidden_field_tag :data_filtered, :value => @data_filtered %>
    </div>
```

My javascript is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    freezeTopRow($('#dataTable'));
    $("#export").click(function(){
        var data1 = $("#data_filtered").val()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "export",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {data_filtered: data1}
        });
    });
});
```

My controller is

```
  def export
    CSV.open("data.csv", "wb") do |csv|
       csv << params[:data_filtered].first.keys
       @data_filtered.each do |hash|
       csv << hash.values
      end
    end
  end
```

When I view params[:data_filtered] after it has been returned to the controller i see a string:

```
 "{:value=>[{"a"=>nil, "b"=>nil, "c"=>0}]}"
```

But I want it to be in its original form of (array of hashes, in this case just 1 hash)  half the problem is the :value.  I don't want that to be stored and I don't know how to parse that to get just the array. Basically i want

```
[{"a"=>nil, "b"=>nil, "c"=>0]
```

Comment: What is `@data_filtered` in your view? Is it a Hash perhaps?

Comment: @data_filtered is an array of hashes

Comment: Have you considered serializing it manually to a known format so that you can easily unpack it? You're getting the result of calling `to_s` and that's not meant to be easily parsed. If you use JSON then parsing becomes easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try to send json data instead of string(that contains hash). If you send string via ajax then in controller you have to `eval` the params which has SEVERE SECURITY issue.

using `eval`: (PLEASE DONT USE IT)

```
eval('{:value=>[{"a"=>nil, "b"=>nil, "c"=>0}]}') will produce the original hash: {:value=>[{"a"=>nil, "b"=>nil, "c"=>0}]}
```

Comment: how do I send json data instead of the string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762735/access-posted-json-data-from-ajax-in-rails-controller

Comment: how is that different then what i am doing?

Comment: you can find the difference if you inspect the parameter. In current implementation params[:data_filtered] is  just a string, but if you send data like: `data: {data_filtered: {value: [...]}}` then you can get the actual parameters using `params[:data_filtered][:value]` in your controller

Comment: the problem is still the same. now params[:data_filtered][:value] = {:value=>[{"a"=>nil, "b"=>nil, "c"=>0}]} but I want just [{"a"=>nil, "b"=>nil, "c"=>0}]

Comment: Please don't use eval if you have any consideration with security